# Average of top 4 numbers greater than 0 Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I am having trouble finding a formula that finds the top 4 numbers in a row that are all greater than 0, and if there are less than 4 numbers greater than 0 it finds the average of those numbers.
example:

```
 A B C D E F G H    
 1 2 0 0 4 0 0 0
```

I would want the formula to see that there are only 3 numbers greater than 0 and find the average of those 3 numbers without taking any of the 0's into regard.
I thought that `=average(large(isnumber(A1:H1),{1,2,3,4})` would work, but it's not. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a limitation on which version of excel you are using? This type of thing is made much easier with `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS` functions.

Comment: @DavidS as far as I know, there is no reliable way to limit the average to the top 4 values that are not `0` with either `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`.  If there is, please answer the question with a working example.  I would love to learn something new today.

Comment: @ScottCraner Your answer appears to be the best. The use of an array function can be avoided with `SUMPRODUCT`, but that will add a lot of error potential with using a sum/count method. I don't think I'll find a better alternative.

Comment: @DavidS SUMPRODUCT is an array formula.  It is native array formula so Ctrl-Shift-Enter is not needed but it still is an array formula.

Answer (score 3):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE($A1:$H1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MIN(COUNTIF($A1:$H1,">0"),4)))))
```

The `ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MIN(COUNTIF($A1:$H1,">0"),4))` will create an array of 1 to the the number of cells greater than `0` or `4` which ever is the least.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data from the other answer, this produces the same results.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:H1, A1:H1, ">="&IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14, 7, A1:H1/(A1:H1>0), 4), AGGREGATE(15, 7, A1:H1/(A1:H1>0), 1)))
```